# how to find which columns are removed?

Tags: matlab

lets say I have a matrix, 
then I find which columns have variance of zero by

```
var(X)
```

then I remove those with zero variance.

I want to know the ID of those that are variance zero

Comment: To know which columns has variance 0- `ID=var(X)==0;` to remove these columns- `X(:,ID)=[];`

Answer (score 1):

Comparing with zero is very dangerous if you're talking about it in a computational stand point because there are some values where they aren't quite zero, but they might as well be because of floating point precision.  What I would recommend you do is compare with a small tolerance... say... `1e-20`.

Once you establish this tolerance, you simply calculate the variance as normal, but you check to see if each column is less than this tolerance.  `var` computes the variance of each column in a 2D matrix by default, so do something like this:

```
tol = 1e-20;
check = var(X) < tol;
```

`check` will contain a `logical` array where `0` denotes a column that isn't "zero" and `1` denotes that it is.  If you want the physical column numbers, you can make a call to [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html):

```
numbers = find(check);
```

Next, if you want to remove the columns, simply index into `X` with the `logical` array you created above and `null` them:

```
X(:, check) = [];
```